# sseEmitter complete when refresh the page in browser

Tags: java, angular, notifications, server-sent-events

i am implementing notification system using sse emitter,
1-the client call for subscribe APi and the server create new ssEmtter and return it to the client

```
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000l);

    emitterService.addEmitter(sseEmitter);

    log.info("subscribed");
    return sseEmitter;
}
```

2- in publish the server use this sseEmiter and send the message

my question is when i refresh the page in browser then the server try to send message i got this exception
how could i keep the connection of sse emitter live even i refresh the page in the browser
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ResponseBodyEmitter has already completed
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:196)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:126)
at com.efinance.service.entity.service.EmitterServiceImpl.lambda$2(EmitterServiceImpl.java:102)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at com.efinance.service.entity.service.EmitterServiceImpl.pushNotification(EmitterServiceImpl.java:95)
at com.efinance.service.entity.service.EmitterServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9e4e84c6.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
at com.efinance.service.entity.service.EmitterServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2c5d230.pushNotification(<generated>)
at com.efinance.service.entity.service.EntityPansUnderThresholdJob.notifyEntityPansUnderThreshold(EntityPansUnderThresholdJob.java:57)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:774)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
at com.efinance.service.entity.tenant.TenantAspect.lambda$0(TenantAspect.java:36)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
at com.efinance.service.entity.tenant.TenantAspect.handelTenantNames(TenantAspect.java:29)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
at com.efinance.service.entity.service.EntityPansUnderThresholdJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e85299cc.notifyEntityPansUnderThreshold(<generated>)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

for client i am using angular

```
console.log('call subscripe'); const eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill(('http://localhost:8587/subscription'), { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("token") }, heartbeatTimeout: 1000000 });
eventSource.onopen = (e) => console.log("open");
eventSource.onmessage = (e) => { console.log(e)}
eventSource.onerror = (e) => {
  if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    console.log("close");
  } else {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

how could i keep the connection of sse emitter live even i refresh the page in the browser?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh. You have to subscribe your client again.

This will create a new SseEmitter in the backend. Then when you want to send new data from the backend send to all relevant SseEmitters.

One will succeed, the others will fail sending from the backend (because the refresh destroyed the old eventSource listeners on the frontend). Remove those failed from your emitterService.