# Send info from Angular to Java to use LOGGER.info for logging purposes

Tags: java, angular

At first I had hoped to skate by, by using a console.log(); in the ui, but as I suspected, I don't think our logging, even though the UI is a service, will catch it.

I'm searching, not finding a way to do this, short of possibly an npm library like ngx-logger, but unclear if that will work, or just creating an entire new endpoint for this express purpose, so thought I'd ask first:

I need to send some info from a button click in Angular (9, if it makes a difference) to Java to use it in a LOGGER.info for logging purposes - is there an easy way of doing this, or do I need to create an endpoint, etc..?

Comment: I think this guy is doing something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589565/sseemitter-complete-when-refresh-the-page-in-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to create an end point for this.
A RESTful application only interacts with front end via end points only.

By the way, I am also assuming that your application would also be sending API  calls to perform action. These actions themselves can print additional informaation like - User X shooped for product Y, so you don't always have to log via front end.

TLDR: Yes. An end point is required. Though you can buffer them at front end, send it one go.

Comment: I knew it after I posted this - creating new endpoint now, lol! Thank you Gaurav!

Comment: You’re welcome. :)